# Method onsuccess in Scala Future

Tags: scala, future

I have future that compute some computation and i want to take the result. I have to use variant Await.result(...) (it works fine). But there is **onSuccess**
 method in Future, but it doesn't ensure that i take result before computation finishes. What is purpose and scope of using onSuccess method in Future?

Comment: typically, you want to avoid using `Await.result`, as it blocks on a `Future` and often removes the benefit of using the `Future` in the first place (avoiding blocking). there are ofcourse exceptions (sometimes in tests), but i find them to be rare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onSuccess` is non-blocking.

```
val f = Future { Thread.sleep(1000) }
f.onSuccess { case _ => println("success" }
println("before success")
```

This will output:

```
before success
success
```

`onSuccess` will always be executed when the future successfully completes. The main advantage of this approach is that you are able to move on and do other things while waiting for the future to complete.

With `Await.result`, it will not move on to the next line until the `Future` completes.

Comment: That's fine, that's a great way to operate on the results of futures.

Comment: but if i have code like this `val sumF = Future { (1L to 100000L).sum }; sumF onSuccess { case s => println(s) }` I have no guarantee that i can see the result in console

Comment: You won't use futures all of a sudden. It's a question of your applications approach. Do you want to go the asynchronous style or not. It it needed? And so on.

Comment: i suppose that  onSuccess is not relevant in this case: `val sumF = Future { (1L to 100000L).sum }; sumF onSuccess { case s => println(s) }`. But how i can correctly choose what i should use onSuccess or Await.result?

Comment: use onSuccess if you don't want to block other operations. Use Await.result if you need the value of the future before you move on. There are other ways to compose operations on futures without Await.result as well. see: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html

Comment: Thank you, it clarified the situation. But, is the a way which ensure on 100 % that onSuccess will end before application ends?

Comment: If it's a short lived program, instead of something like a server, just use Await.result. You only really get the benefits of not blocking when your application is highly concurrent.

Answer (score 0):

It's an asynchronous approach and makes use of inversion of control. This means that when your Future finishes, the result can be handled. You could also put your final computation into the Futures onSuccess and only if the result is there, it will be computed. If you need to return the result somewhere and not via a callback for example you would need to wait for the Future or simply return it and handle it's result where it's needed.